# Non-MOSS equivalents to MOSS Outlook Web Parts

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, outlook, dotnetnuke, exchange-server

We are building an intranet portal not built on Microsoft SharePoint (MOSS) but on DotNetNuke 5.6.1.  However, one of the pieces of functionality that is desired is the ability for staff members to view corporate calendars, their inbox, contact lists and Global Address list on the site.  The backend for this data is Microsoft Exchange Server 2007.

There are some web parts that come with MOSS 2007 that provide this sort of functionality, or at least appear to based on their names: "My Inbox", "My Calendars", "My Contacts", etc.  I have been looking for some equivalent third party controls and have not been able to find anything.  Does anyone know of anything out here that would suit our needs?

We are looking for a solution that simply displays this data from Exchange, we don't want to have to copy it to a separate store and try to keep the two synchronized.  Ideally it would permit users to interact with that data (send replies, add calendar events, etc.) but that may be a bridge too far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DNN have you tried putting OWA (Outlook Web Access) inside an iFrame?

Comment: Yes, in fact I did a demo with that approach.  It has several drawbacks.  As I recall, i was unable to find a URL that would  display a calendar hosted in a public folder, nor did the web parts size themselves to their frames very well.  but we are keeping it in our pocket as an approach of last resort.